# Return of Mongod Query Distinct

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, distinct-values

I have the next problem:
When I do a query with a distinct, only returns a array of name properties, example:

```
var promise = clients.distinct("name", {"id_client_group": id_clientGroup, "id_client": id_client, "status": "active"}).exec();
```

return this:

```
["client2, client3"]
```

When I would need all the properties of the object
Example:

```
[
{
    name: "client1",
    mail: "mail@1"
},
{
     name: "client2",
     mail: "mail@2"
}
]
```

I have tried to do a normal search and returns the array of objects complete

Comment: What result you expect for documents with same name but different mail?

Comment: Thanks @AlexBlex, The result is an example, what I need is the type of data.

Comment: Define "type of data". What does it mean?

Comment: @AlexBlex, Sorry, for my explanation. I mean that when doing "distinct" I get an array with the different "names", I need an array with the complete object, not just the name

Comment: I get this part. I am asking what you expect in the results if 2 objects have the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the mongodb driver [API doc](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#distinct), this is the expected behaviour for distinct.

> The distinct command returns returns a list of distinct values for the given key across a collection.

You should try aggregation instead, but I'm not sure what kind of data you are looking for in case of repeated data.

```
clients.aggregate([
    {$match: {"id_client_group": id_clientGroup, "id_client": id_client, "status": "active"}},
    {$group: {_id: "$name", mail:{$first:"$mail"}}}
])
```

You might want to try some other expression in the group stage, checkout the doc [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Comment: You can replace `mail:{$first:"$mail"}` with `data:{$push:"$$ROOT"}`  to get the whole document.I believe that's what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.